# Hibernate query exception expecting d found f

Tags: java, hibernate

I got this exception,

> org.hibernate.QueryException: expecting 'd', found 'f' [from
>   com.carre.model.ProductOrder where sessieid =
>   4f5bf46709a6886e764207a00ec0]

code form controller:

```
 Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();      
 String sessieid = cookies[0].getValue();
 model.addAttribute("listProductorderNieuw", this.productorderService.listProductorderNieuw(sessieid));
```

code form DAO:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<ProductOrder> listProductorderNieuw(String id) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
     List<ProductOrder> productList = session.createQuery("from ProductOrder where sessieid = " + id).list();
    for (ProductOrder p : productList) {
        logger.info("ProductOrder List::" + p);
    }
    return productList;
}
```

I have no idea where this exception is coming from.

Someone can help?

Comment: please provide a full stacktrace of exception you encounter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using named paramner as follows

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from ProductOrder where sessieid = :id ");
query.setParameter("id", id);
List<ProductOrder> productList = query.list();
```